# cordova error while installing using npm

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

C:\Users\bisho melek>npm install -g cordova
(node:6848) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are
 using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\bisho melek\App
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\bisho melek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node
_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\bisho melek\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\bish
o melek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_m
odules'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\b
isho melek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\nod
e_modules'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -4094,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\Users\bisho melek\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bisho melek\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have package.json file in your project root directory.You can either create one manually or run this in your project root

```
npm init
```

Then try installing cordova. Good luck :)

Comment: I'm sorry but which project you mean exactly ?

Comment: I did as you said ..but take a look at this error i upload it for you https://ufile.io/26e

Comment: {
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true
} set this in your package.json

Comment: can you share your package.json ?

Comment: add this ( "private": true,  ) below (  "version": "1.0.0", ) in your package.json

Comment: plz help ..  I have been with this problem long time ago

Comment: Your terminal error is saying two or more things ,  I will suggest you few links . try those out https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11265 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901999/how-to-fix-cordova-is-not-recognized-in-command-line-windows-8 . maybe these will help you out