# Ionic Capacitor problem with Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to use facebook-connect ionic cordova plugin and I have a problem, i can't add the facebook SDK as they say here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/

In the link they say to put $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook-connect --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

but it doesn't work, it says :
"The term 'cordova' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
how can i add to capacitor?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should set up your environment correctly. Command `cordova` doesn't set properly. Check this question: [How to fix 'cordova' is not recognized in the Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901999/how-to-fix-cordova-is-not-recognized-in-the-windows-command-prompt)

Also, probably you should set up variables manually for the plugin:
[How to set Cordova plugin variables in a Capacitor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64421414/how-to-set-cordova-plugin-variables-in-a-capacitor-app)